# Is VGA as good (ok) as HDMI for everyday computing and graphic design?

Tags: hdmi, vga

My HDMI port is broken on my new monitor (still under warranty) so I plugged in my VGA , and there doesn't seem to be any difference.

I really don't feel like waiting 6 weeks for LG to fix the monitor, and they it might not even be fixed, cause it always flickered when moving it around, even as new, the port is too flimsy...

It seems VGA is not as crisp as HDMI, but this could very well be my imagination!

I have to look very hard, and I "think" it looks better on HDMI, but I couldn't be sure...!

I don't use Blue Ray or 4K, my monitor is 1080*1920, 24 inches

Am I ok with VGA?

Comment: Just to give some background: VGA quality depends a lot of the computer (of graphics cards)'s RAMDAC quality, cable quility and cable length. HDMI (or DP or any digital cable) might look a lot better when you need s 3m cable for a 4k screen.  But for most short cables and onlu 1080x1920 is should not be an issue.

Comment: Cable is 5 meters, using i5-8400 with stock Intel Graphics,  monitor is new 1080*1920, 24 inches Logitech

Answer (score 5):

You are essentially asking is analog (VGA) as good as digital (HDMI).  In some respects, it is.  In others, it is not.

For "general computing" it is fine.  You said yourself, you are struggling to see a difference.  A quality analog signal can very well be visibly indistinguishable from digital.

As for graphic design, a valid argument can be made against it.  Since the data is being converted from digital, to analog, then to digital again, color data and pixel perfect accuracy can be diminished.  However, people did graphic design this way for decades.  Not to mention, even with digital displays, without proper color profiles or calibration, the color will still be off.  Additionally, digital displays are rasterized, working with vector images means there is always a chance for dispay innacuracy.

In the end, digital is better for accuracy, but how much better is up to the individual.

Comment: That's what I figured, actually, a lot of monitors don't even have HDMI adapters, they still sell em. And I lived without HDMI before, I didn't go blind and always have been able to work! From what I understand, the lack of sound would be the biggest difference. The monitor is brand new, and the pc also pretty much brand new 8th gen i5-8400, so hardware is all good

Comment: Additionally, I find HDMI very unreliable, finicky and fragile, but that might be because of the hardware, this LG port is very flimsy, and the mother board is an AsRock z370pro 4